# How to select balanced random sample records from two tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In order to train the machine learning model I have to retrieve a sample of users which consists of balanced numbers of current users and former users. Tha database consists of tables all_users and former_users.

In case of unbalanced sample (100 records) the following query returns the records with desired columns:

```
SELECT t1.user_property1, t2.user_property2, t3.valid_to FROM additional_info t1 LEFT JOIN all_users t2 ON t1.user_ID = t2.user_ID LEFT JOIN former_users t3 ON t1.user_ID = t3.user_ID ORDER BY random() LIMIT 100
```

In order to get the balanced sample, there should be half records with users which are stored in table former_users and half from table all_users which, in the same time, are not in table former_users (otherwise the sample wouldn't be balanced).

Does anyone know, what is the most convenient way to retrieve the balanced random sample from tables all_users and former_users along the additional properties from table additional_info?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the following:

```
(SELECT t1.user_property1, t2.user_property2, t3.valid_to FROM additional_info t1 LEFT JOIN all_users t2 ON t1.user_ID = t2.user_ID INNER JOIN former_users t3 ON t1.user_ID = t3.user_ID ORDER BY random() LIMIT 50)
UNION
(SELECT t1.user_property1, t2.user_property2, NULL FROM additional_info t1 LEFT JOIN all_users t2 ON t1.user_ID = t2.user_ID WHERE t1.user NOT IN (SELECT user_ID FROM former_users) ORDER BY random() LIMIT 50)
```

but was looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might consider doing is:

```
Query 1 - SELECTS random non-former users joined to additional_info with a LIMIT of 50
Query 2 - SELECTS random former users joined to additional_info with a LIMIT of 50
```

and then combine the results with a UNION

```
(Query 1) UNION (Query 2)
```

This will give you random results for both criteria, with a total of 100 users.

Comment: You should use UNION ALL in this case rather than UNION.  The latter adds an additional step to remove duplicates, which is not necessary.

Comment: there is no table non-former users. I was actually wondering whether there is a way for 'negating join'.

Comment: The solution you just posted was what I would have done (just didn't have the schema to actually create sql). The only other thing I can think would be to do an outer join and check that a field from the third table IS NULL or IS NOT NULL instead of the NOT IN. Either way, it probably not much different and I can't think of a simpler solution.